# Multiple media encode and Merge (join) media file in azure

Tags: azure

I am new to azure, I ref media encoding sample tutorial & it working fine too,

but when I upload multiple file it successfully upload but while encoding job, my job.Submit(); method throw an exception

and another is I want single file in output (in short I want merge video files and add some snaps in between video)

Answer (score 0):

No, currently (as of October the 7th) you can't join/combine multiple files into single one.

As for the errors you get while `job.Submit()` - in order to receive a proper answer, you have to ask the question properly - provide relevant code lines/snippet, full stack trace, exact steps to reproduce etc.

Also, then doing media trans-coding, always keep an eye on the [list of supported media codecs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973634.aspx). Make sure you are using supported codecs before asking question.

Comment: ,yes I have ref list of supported codecs, I ref http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/tutorials/get-started/ this link to understand media upload,encode and download but it is for single media only,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129584.aspx this one for multiple media upload, after upload multiple media ,I call "CreateEncodingJob" method then job.submit() throws exception....

Answer (score 0):

Azure's Media Encoder Stander (MES) supports combining multiple video files using a custom preset.

[Azure MES Doc: Concatenate two or more video files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#concatenate)