# WinJS Combining Video Files

Tags: video, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation or anything that references how to combine multiple video files into a single video in a Windows 8.1 App.

I'm building a Windows 8.1 application using WinJS that will require the user to record multiple separate clips and then be render a single video file of these clips (one after another).

Capturing the video and saving the clips is no problem, but I have yet to find a reference about how to combine the clips into a single video.

It seems like I might be able to use Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSource, but couldn't gain much more than that from reading the MSDN docs.

I realize I might also be able/need to use a lower level library to do this, any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Comment: I definitely think you'll need a lower-level video-processing library... but I have no idea which one (or how to implement it). I'm very interested to see if what you come up with though!

Comment: Have a look at this, this component is used to generate video files from individual frames, I know this is not your exact requirement, bt this code may help you.. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to do some cloud processing for this. Maybe check into something like parse cloud, or azure cloud. Also there are some JS libraries that may help with this. It sounds like a mostly custom implementation however

Comment: I've read elsewhere that Azure Media Services does not support joining media files. Doubt Parse can do it, and probably not Azure without significant server implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223509/multile-media-encode-and-merge-join-media-file-in-azure